# Kernel upgrade issue

Tags: centos, vps, kernel

I am trying to upgrade kernel on OnApp VM. Currently installed kernel is 2.6.32-279.22.1.el6.x86_64. The new version available is 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64.

I installed new kernel 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64 and rebooted the server, however the server is still booting with old kernel. No errors in /var/log/messages.

I rebooted the server by setting default kernel to 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64 in grub console.

I have also heard this is a known issue with OnApp. Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Contact your service provider.

Comment: I contacted them. They provided me knowledge base URL https://onapp.zendesk.com/categories/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=centos+kernel&for_search=1

Comment: I didn't find anything relevant to my issue.